# Combining two python scripts, one reading an IMU another one moving a servo motor

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, servo, mpu6050

I am very new in python, but I have been able to make few useful python codes (at least useful for my work). I would like to combine two python scripts, but I have a hard time making it work, I think I am completely lost in how things should look like.The end goal is to have my Raspberry reading the sensor while also the servo moves.

Here is the the IMU script

```
from mpu6050 import mpu6050
import time
mpu = mpu6050(0x68)

while True:
    print("Temp : "+str(mpu.get_temp()))
    print()

    accel_data = mpu.get_accel_data()
    print("Acc X : "+str(accel_data['x']))
    print("Acc Y : "+str(accel_data['y']))
    print("Acc Z : "+str(accel_data['z']))
    print()

    gyro_data = mpu.get_gyro_data()
    print("Gyro X : "+str(gyro_data['x']))
    print("Gyro Y : "+str(gyro_data['y']))
    print("Gyro Z : "+str(gyro_data['z']))  
    print()
    print("-------------------------------")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Servo motor scripts

```
# Servo1.py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

P_SERVO = 22 # adapt to your wiring
fPWM = 50  # Hz (not higher with software PWM)
a = 10
b = 2

def setup():
    global pwm
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(P_SERVO, GPIO.OUT)
    pwm = GPIO.PWM(P_SERVO, fPWM)
    pwm.start(0)

def setDirection(direction):
    duty = a / 180 * direction + b
    pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(duty)
    print "direction =", direction, "-> duty =", duty
    time.sleep(1) # allow to settle
   
print "starting"
setup()
for direction in range(0, 181, 10):
    setDirection(direction)
direction = 0    
setDirection(0)    
GPIO.cleanup() 
print "done"
```

Comment: Why do you have `direction = 0` followed by `setDirection(0)`? Also, it looks like you'll have to have some logic in the while loop that, once triggered, sets a direction to the servos.

Comment: Good question. Let me check that